# angular2 http response converter

Tags: jquery, angular, converters, response

I'm trying to fetch images from flickr's feed end point (see below). The response for some searches responds with an invalid json format containing a single quote.

In Jquery we have access to converters (see code below) it basically manipulates the response before receiving (works great), is there a similar method available to angular 2 as yet?

PS: "https://crossorigin.me/" is required to avoid CORS errors.

Here's a plunker [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/tD4OHuXZw4R3zrznUuGh?p=info)

JQUERY METHOD:

```
let urlCall = `https://crossorigin.me/https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=${query}&format=json&nojsoncallback=1`;

$.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: urlCall,
      dataType: 'json',
      async: true,
      converters: {
          "text json": function (textValue) {
              return $.parseJSON(textValue.replace(/(^|[^\\])\\'/g, "$1'"));
          }
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var photo = [];

        return $.map(data.items,function (photo) {
          photo.url   = photo.media.m;
          photo.title = photo.title;
          photo.description = $(photo.description).text();
          photo.tags = photo.tags.split(" ");
        })

      }, error: function(data) {
        //error consoloe
        console.log('ERROR - AJAX CALL');
      }

    });
```

Angular method:

```
return this._http.get(urlCall, { headers: headers })
         .map(res => res.json())
         .map((val) => {
                 return val.items.map((photo: any) => {
                     return {
                         url: photo.media.m,
                         title: photo.title
                     }
                 })
         })
        .catch((error:any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error'));
```

Comment: There isn't such thing. And honestly I don't see much benefit in it. Why's it so much different then just converting it when you get it?

Comment: By the time i get it, error already happened straight into "error". Unless i'm doing something wrong?